Is there a reliable method to recover when URLSession encounters the SSL error -9816?
For a number of years we have seen a problem where our app enters a state where it is unable to communicate to our server domain after the SSL error -9816.
Error recorded from 3rd party error logging solutions, which operate on different endpoint domains:
NSUnderlyingError": Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9816, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9816, _NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: pdp_ip0[lte], ipv4, dns, expensive, uses cell}, "_NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey": LocalDataTask <DEDBFA4D-810D-4438-A6A0-95E3B9668B9E>.<308>, "_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey": 3, "_NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey": <__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x301f82e60>( LocalDataTask <DEDBFA4D-810D-4438-A6A0-95E3B9668B9E>.<308> )

"NSLocalizedDescription": An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., "NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion": Would you like to connect to the server anyway?

We posted the problem on the Apple Developer forum but we have not received a follow-up response after trying the suggestion in a reply from an Apple engineer: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/762158
---
Characteristics:

We think it is something managed by iOS operating system for the app because the only methods to reliably exit the locked state are:

delete and reinstall the app, or

after the app is updated with a new install

waiting a few days



The device/app has no problem connecting to other domains, e.g. the 3rd party service to log the error. Other apps on the device have no problems connecting to the Internet.

Our domain is working for other apps whilst the instances of our app reporting the error are stuck returning the same -9816 errors for any subsequent request to our domain.

Mostly seems to occur with mobile/cell data. Switching to WIFI data can resolve the problem but as soon as the mobile/cell data is used again the problem returns immediately. We think there have cases with WIFI data.

The SSL error occurs most prevalently after a server outage. We are unable to replicate the problem on demand despite our server engineers' best efforts. As we cannot replicate the problem we cannot submit a code-level support request to Apple because of the "Do you have a focused test project that demonstrates your issue?" requirement.


Implementation Notes:
We have one shared instance of the URLSession in the app for its networking to avoid the problems of multiple URLSession instances.
URLSession configuration:
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 22
config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
config.urlCache = nil

We added conditions to call the URLSession await reset() method when detecting the SSL errors before repeating the request. We still see subsequent requests hitting the same -9816 error.
We have also tried the following as per the Apple engineer's suggestion:
urlRequest.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData

The policy seemed to have no impact on the error.

Apparently this error indicates the server closed down the TCP connection without providing a proper SSL close notify alert first. There is no obvious single cause for such errors, misconfigured servers and middle boxes or incompatible protocols are possibilities. I would want to see a packet-level capture from Wireshark to see exactly where in the TLS protocol the connection is terminated. But you are also saying that you are unable to attempt a reconnect after the error? What does you code do when it encounters such an error?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Currently when we get the error we call the reset() method on the URLSession instance and then automatically attempt to repeat the network. And when that fails we display an error to the user (in addition to logging it on 3rd party services). Typically at that stage the user has to delete and reinstall the app the URL session can connect to the same domain again despite other instances of the same app on the same network providers being able to connect to the domain.
